# Alert dialog if user wants to leave the fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-fragmentactivity

I'm struggling with a problem. I have an activity with a bunch of fragments inside. I want to add alert dialog that will require confirmation that the user actually wants to leave the specifed fragment. It should work both If the user click on another fragment or press the back button. How can I achive it? I tried to call that alert inside onStop() but the fragment changes before alert shows up. How can I stop the action and wait for user confirmation?

Comment: Can you post the code for showing the alert dialog? The more context you provide, the better answer you can get.

Comment: Are you overriding the onBackPressed() method from the fragment? This is the only way I know in order to add behaviors when user press the back button.

Comment: You should write a back button handler as outlined here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back That way you can intercept the event, show the dialog, and then turn off the handler when the user is "allowed" to back out. If you want to stop the user navigating out in other ways, you'll have to write some handling in the code that's doing that navigation. If you're talking about a whole bunch of Fragments where one might start a navigation, and you want to block that if another Fragment is around, that's more complicated and you might want to post more details